# Matlab: interpolate 4 corner values over entire matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, interpolation

I have a 20x23 matrix in Matlab of which the 4 corners have a value:

```
(1,1) = 16.46
(1,23) = 16.16
(20,1) = 16.93
(20,23) = 16.57
```

How can I interpolate these values over the entire 20x23 domain?

Thanks!

Comment: Try [`interp2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example I used `'linear'` interpolation. Below I reference the matrix as sample points where I define the corners of the matrix as coordinates (1,1), (1,2), (2,1) and (2,2). To interpolate the values of the `Matrix` two vectors have to be created to define query points. This acts like a finer grid (spatial domain) that tells the `interp2()` function the points (in between) to interpolate. This of course is a built-in approach and there are alternative methods.

**Some Interpolation Methods Available for `interp2()`:** `'linear'`,`'nearest'`,`'cubic'`,`'spline'`,`'makima'`

[image: Interpolated Matrix Colour Plot]

```
Matrix(1,1) = 16.46; %Top-left corner%
Matrix(1,2) = 16.16; %Top-right corner%
Matrix(2,1) = 16.93; %Bottom-left corner%
Matrix(2,2) = 16.57; %Bottom-right corner%

Width = 23;
Height = 20;

Finer_X_Points = linspace(1,2,Width);
Finer_Y_Points = linspace(1,2,Height)';
Finer_Matrix = interp2(Matrix,Finer_X_Points,Finer_Y_Points,'linear');
```

---

### For Additional Colour Plot:

```
pcolor(flip(Finer_Matrix,1));
title("Interpolated Matrix");
colorbar
axis off
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Answer (score 2):

You're basically doing a single cell of [bilinear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation).

So from the link, the formula you need is

[image: formula]

You could use `interp2`, but to be different from Michael's answer we could also just implement this ourselves...

```
% Setup
x = [1, 23];
y = [1, 20];
z = [16.46, 16.93;
     16.16, 16.57];

% Interpolation function
biLinearInterp = @(xi,yi) ( 1/( (x(2)-x(1))*(y(2)-y(1)) ) ) * ...
                        [x(2)-xi, xi-x(1)] * z * [y(2)-yi; yi-y(1)];

% Create data
[X, Y] = meshgrid( x(1):x(2), y(1):y(2) );
Z = arrayfun( @(xi,yi) biLinearInterp(xi,yi), X, Y );
```

This satisfies your orignal spec that

```
Z(1,1) = 16.46
Z(1,23) = 16.16
Z(20,1) = 16.93
Z(20,23) = 16.57
```

With linear interpolation in between